# How to recover the ideal from grobner basis of kernel of ann(x)

Tags: groebner-bases

M -> ann(x)

i can find the grobner basis of kernel of ann(x) and need the final step to recover this basis to ideal

as i know, eliminate is not for all cases, what is the general practice to treat this case? i do not have a real example of this. Hope an example.

which book teach this to convert basis back to ideals, if have maple code will be more understandable

Comment: Crossposted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368027/how-to-recover-the-ideal-from-grobner-basis-of-kernel-of-annx

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just assume that your notation is meanful as in common com. algebra.

An easy ref. may be founded in J.B. Fraleigh's *First course in Abstract Algebra*. Sec 28(I do not remeber the number for sure) And as for algebraic geometry, I really know nothing.

A thorough ref. is W.W. Adams and Loustaunnau's *An Introduction to Grobner Bases*, personal favorite.

About Elimination method, I remember there is a section about it in Waerden's moder algebra...I don't know what is a general method, maybe you can search for some papers.